# how to solve docker error of "Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm following [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build) link to making a docker-compose.yml file but it will giving me the same issue does not find the docker file while I'm mentioning that in the `docker-compose.yml` see my code:-

```
version: '2'
 services:
  web:
   build: .
   ports:
    - "8000:8000"

users:
  build:
    context: ./users
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  image: cinema/movies
  container_name: cinema-movies
  environment:
    VIRTUAL_HOST: movies.local
```

And `docker-compose.yml` file is in the `bkapiv` folder the folder structure is :-

```
 bkapiv(Folder)------users(Folder)
   |                  |
   |                   ------Dockerfile
   |
    ---------docker-compose.yml
```

How will I resolve my issue that I will run my first api on local using docker.

Comment: How do u run the docker-compose?

Comment: `sudo docker-compose up` by this command

Comment: u mean to i have to write it like this `context: ./users/Dockerfile`?  or `build: ./users/Dockerfile` I used both gave same error

Answer (score 3):

```
web:
   build: .
```

I think error throwing from `web` container, commented out the `users` and run the docker-compose, you need a Dockerfile in `web` too. Also try other way around. The you can understand which container produce the error. Because users looks fine for me according to your folder structure. Plus you have an extra space in `services:`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the web service, you specified that it should build a Dockerfile in your current dir but there is no Dockerfile there.